# Can't get this table and constraint right in SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

I'm doing this exercise and and I can't get it right - can anybody help me this?

> *Write a second script called `2_CreateTables.sql` that will create the `Department` and `Employees` tables in the `FinalExam` database with the following information:*

`Department` table Information:

```
Column Name     Data Type                         Allow Nulls?
--------------------------------------------------------------
DepartmentID    Integer                           No
DepartmentName  Variable length character data    No
GroupName       Variable length character data    Yes
ModifiedDate    Small date and time               No
```

AutoNumber:

Make the `DepartmentID` automatically number starting with 100 and increment by 5.

**Constraints**:

1. The `DepartmentID` column will be defined as a clustered primary key called `PK_Department_DepartmentID`.
2. The `ModifiedDate` column will have a default constraint called `DF_DeptModified` with the system date and time as the default value.

This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE Deparment
    DeparmentID  int not null,
    DeparmentName varchar(100) not null,
    GroupName varchar(50) null,
    ModifiedDate datetime  not null,
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using **SQL Server** - try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Department
    (DepartmentID INT IDENTITY(100, 5) NOT NULL,
     DepartmentName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     GroupName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     ModifiedDate SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_DeptModified DEFAULT(GETDATE()),

     CONSTRAINT PK_Department_DepartmentID
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (DepartmentID)
    )
GO
```

Changes made:

- make sure you have starting and ending parenthesis `( )` after your `CREATE TABLE (name)` statement
- added the `IDENTITY(100, 5)` clause to the `DepartmentID` to make it auto-numbering according to the requirements
- changed the datatype of `ModifiedDate` to be `SMALLDATETIME` as defined in the textual requirements (you had `DATETIME`)
- fixed all the `Deparment` to `Department`
- added the default constraint for `ModifiedDate`
- added the table constraint for the clustered primary key

Comment: Might be worth highlighting that you're corrected a data type from the OPs question.